# python 3 guessing game 'while' statement turns into an infinite loop when True for some reason

Tags: python

I tried this on both pyCharm and IDLE. Both have same results. I don't understand why if the while statement is set to true it prints out the first print line infinitely.. even when I set it to false after the user guesses the number correctly.

```
    import random

    def Main():
        number = random.randint(1,100)
        playing = True                                  # figure out stupid True infinite loop ~~

        print("Welcome !\n")

        while (playing):
            print("Guess A Number Between 1 & 100: ")

        guess = int(input("Your Guess: "))

        if guess == number:
            print("Congratulations !")                  # maybe add a 'your number was' thing ~
            playing = False

        elif guess > number:
            print(int(input("Guess Lower: ")))

        else:
            print(int(input("Guess Higher: ")))



    if __name__ == "__main__":
        Main()
```

Comment: You have already asked this question. You need to ***indent*** whatever you want to be within your while loop, as currently the only thing in it is your `print` statement. As a result, it will evaluate to true forever. ***Indent*** whatever you want in your `while` loop properly.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing inside the `while` loop is that `print()` statement. Fix your indentation.

Answer (score -1):

This is an extrapolation of what you need to do, *using a function* to make clear you have to perform the whole set of actions inside the while loop:

```
import random

def Main():
    number = random.randint(1,100)
    playing = True                                  # figure out stupid True infinite loop ~~

    print("Welcome !\n")

    while (playing):
        RunGameCycle()

def RunGameCycle():

    """ Everything inside this function is what should happend each loop,
        but wasn't because you haven't indented properly """

    print("Guess A Number Between 1 & 100: ")

    guess = int(input("Your Guess: "))

    if guess == number:
        print("Congratulations !")                  # maybe add a 'your number was' thing ~
        playing = False

    elif guess > number:
        print(int(input("Guess Lower: ")))

    else:
        print(int(input("Guess Higher: ")))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

Comment: Not my downvote. but this could probably just confuse OP even more as to why his `while` loop isn't working properly. If he doesn't understand indentation, in future attempts he could just start throwing everything in loops in another function.

Comment: @DonkeyKong I understand and agree. I am currently studying "clean code" stuff a lot, and this refactoring (moving loop entrails to another function) is becoming second nature. So, if OP excuses me, I would suggest him to consider this as well: either this specific refactoring and also clean code recommendations in general.

Comment: @heltonbiker Sure thing, I just thought it was worth noting :)